# Where is the salt stored for password_hash?

Tags: php, password-protection

According to (relatively) new PHP documentation:

The [password_hash](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) function uses a random salt (which we should not worry about.. O_O), so if I understand correctly the salt has to be stored somewhere, else the user won't be able to login after registering to a website (different salt => different hash.)

The function documentation doesn't tell anything about interaction with a DB, and since I think storing per-user data is scalable only with a DB, where the heck does that function store the random salt? A `txt` file like session data?

Comment: Using the defaults, the salt is stored in the hash. You did read the "fabulous" manual, right? I mean, thoroughly?

Comment: *"The function documentation doesn't tell anything about interaction with a DB"* - Why should it? That's your job. *Keep on Truckin'!*, I mean *Googlin'!* ;-)

Comment: oh got that.. O_O thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Let's learn by example from what everyone else is telling you:

```
$options = [
    'cost' => 11,
    'salt' => 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuv',
];
echo password_hash("rasmuslerdorf", PASSWORD_DEFAULT, $options)."\n";
```

Output:

> $2y$**11**$**abcdefghijklmnopqrstu**u7aZVUzfW85EB4mHER81Oudv/rT.rmWm

The bolded parts are your cost and salt, respectively embedded in the resulting hash.

You can spit this back into [`password_verify`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) and it will handle it accordingly:

```
print_r(password_verify('rasmuslerdorf', '$2y$11$abcdefghijklmnopqrstuu7aZVUzfW85EB4mHER81Oudv/rT.rmWm')); // true
```

Comment: Higher the cost, higher the stress on the CPU ;-) Put that up to 50 and see how long it'll take to hash that puppy lol

Comment: @Fred-ii- Haha, I just pulled it from one of the examples in the docs, then modified the generated hash to a known value.

Comment: I remember using a value of 20 for the cost, took like 20-30 seconds to process lol One second per additional cost over or equal 20? That sounds about right ;-)

Comment: read the docs and this helped quite a bit with the **bold**! Good basic explanation.

Answer (score 5):

The [password_hash manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) states

> The used algorithm, cost and salt are returned as part of the hash.
>   Therefore, all information that's needed to verify the hash is
>   included in it. This allows the password_verify() function to verify
>   the hash without needing separate storage for the salt or algorithm
>   information.

Therefore the salt is already included in the hash you are saving in the db.

Comment: Yeah, it's been said and in more ways than one ;-) Had I known, I'd of made my "comment" an "answer" and cashed in big time! *woohoo!*